# Error "ln: target `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/' is not a directory: No such file or directory" while installing deb package

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-12.04, dpkg

I am trying to install a ".deb" package on a Ubuntu 12:04 machine.
I used the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i myPackage.deb
```

Unfortunately this command does not succeed as it returns the error:

```
ln: target `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/' is not a directory: No such file or directory
```

This is correct since I do not have the `python2.6` directory in my machine, instead I have the `python2.7` directory.

I can I fix this problem?

Comment: It seems like your `.deb` is for Python 2.6. Could you share some details on what is the package in question?

Comment: It is a package that has been internally made here in my company...

Comment: So I get your best shot would be to reach out to the authors, take the source code and repackage it for Python 2.7...

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks a lot!